# Php show users data from mysql with dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

[image]i want to display users data in a table with the dropdown list , the first option shows all the users but when i click a name it still shows all users, i think i have some trouble in my ajax script because it deosn't seem to work

this is the page where i display data :

```
<?php   
//load_data_select.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ntr-ktb123", "absence");  
function fill_emp($connect)  
{  
  $output = '';  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM employés";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       $output = $output."'<option value="'.$row["IdEmp"].'">'.$row["NomEmp"].'</option>'";  
  }  
  return $output;  
 }  
function fill_Abs($connect)  
{  
  $output = '';  
  $sql = "SELECT NomEmp,PrénomEmp,DateD,DateF,CauseAbs,justifié
FROM absence.absences
WHERE 
MONTH(DateF) = MONTH(NOW())
AND
 YEAR(DateF) = YEAR(NOW());";

  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
 echo "<table>
 <tr>
 <th>NomEmp</th>
 <th>PrénomEmp</th>
 <th>DateD</th>
 <th>DateF</th>
 <th>CauseAbs</th>
 <th>justifié<th>
  </tr>"; 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['NomEmp'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['PrénomEmp'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['DateD'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['DateF'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['CauseAbs'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['justifié'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
   }  
   $output="</table>";
   return $output;  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Multiple Image Upload</title>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
 />  
        <script 
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>  
       <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>  
       <style>
 table {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
  }

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#nom').change(function(){  
       var NomEmp = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"usr.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{NomEmp:NomEmp},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_Abs').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });  
 </script> 
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container">  
            <h3>  
              <label for="nom">Selectionnez le nom de l'employé </label>
            </br></br>
                 <select name="nom" id="nom">  
                      <option value="">Tout les employés</option> 
                      <?php echo fill_emp($connect); ?>  
                 </select>  
                 <br /><br /> <br /> 
                 <div class="row" id="show_Abs">  
                      <?php echo fill_Abs($connect);?>  
                 </div>  
            </h3>  
       </div>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

and this is the usr.php :

```
 <?php  
 //load_data.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ntr-ktb123", "absence");  
 $output = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["NomEmp"]))  
 {  
  if($_POST["NomEmp"] != '')  
  {  
       $sql = "SELECT NomEmp,PrénomEmp,DateD,DateF,CauseAbs,justifié
FROM absence.absences
WHERE 
MONTH(DateF) = MONTH(NOW())
AND
YEAR(DateF) = YEAR(NOW()) WHERE NomEmp = '".$_POST["NomEmp"]."'";  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $sql = "SELECT NomEmp,PrénomEmp,DateD,DateF,CauseAbs,justifié
FROM absence.absences
WHERE 
MONTH(DateF) = MONTH(NOW())
AND
 YEAR(DateF) = YEAR(NOW());";  
  }  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
   $output="<table>
 <tr>
 <th>NomEmp</th>
 <th>PrénomEmp</th>
 <th>DateD</th>
 <th>DateF</th>
 <th>CauseAbs</th>
 <th>justifié<th>
 </tr>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
        echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['NomEmp'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['PrénomEmp'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['DateD'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['DateF'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['CauseAbs'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['justifié'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";  
  }  
  echo $output;  
}  
?>
```

can anyone help me to find the problem in this ? any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the ajax call like mentioned below :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
     NomEmp = "";
     $.ajax({  
            url:"usr.php",  
            method:"POST",  
                data:{NomEmp:NomEmp},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#show_Abs').html(data);  
                }  
           });  

  $('#nom').change(function(){  
        NomEmp = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
        url:"usr.php",  
        method:"POST",  
            data:{NomEmp:NomEmp},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_Abs').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
      });  
     });
```

Also in your html cannot able to find a tag having id show_Abs. So just modify the div into

```
<div class="row" id="show_Abs">  
 </div>
```

Now I think the php function  `<?php echo fill_Abs($connect);?>` is not necessary.
When page loads the first time, ajax call will be generated and on changing the select tag call will be generated with passing the selected parameters getting appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a little more info to help with this, but I'll try to get the ball rolling.

I would guess that `$_POST["NomEmp"]` in usr.php is === "" so the else is running, which shows the entire table again.

I can't tell what you are setting the "value" attribute to in the `fill_emp` function. What is the value of `$row[1]` in that function?